# Android ListView set selected item highlight with default

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, highlight, selecteditem

I have a navigation drawer for my app and I want the current navigation selection to stay highlighted. If i set up the listview like this

```
<ListView
                android:id="@+id/navigation_list_drawer"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:dividerHeight="0dp"
                android:divider="@null"
                android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
                android:listSelector="@color/white_transparent"

                 />
```

It remains selected when clicked without calling

```
navigationDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true)
```

in the onclick method (¿is this normal?) but i cant make a default selection since the listview populates asynchronously and when I try to use the setItemChecked in the onStart method of the activity it does nothing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How's your list being populated? If you're using a cursor loader, you can just set the default selection in the `onLoadFinished` method.

Or if you have a custom adapter, override the `getView` method to set whatever item you want as checked.

Comment: Used this solution, modified my custom adapter to set the background to the color I want for highlight and created a method that switches the highlighted item. Thanks!